# Had a small oven fire, how do i get the smoke smell out of the oven?

Tags: oven, cleaning

I was baking a buttermilk pie. I accidentally spilled it as i pushed the oven rack in. The oven caught fire. Now there is a slight smoke smell in the kitchen. I need to get rid of that smell.

Comment: Open the window?

Comment: Is the smell in the kitchen, or just the oven?

Answer (score 4):

Bicarbonate of soda is the most effective agent for removing odours in my experience.

I've used it to detox a fridge that stank of fish after I accidently left fresh seabass in there before going off on holiday.

Just scrub it in using a scourer and warm water, followed by a thorough rinse.

Comment: It's also possible to fill a small tray with Bicarbonate and let it sit there for a day or so, it will absorb particles.

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to ventilate the kitchen.  Open a window, and turn on your hood/ventilator fan if you have one.  Run it for at least 1/2 hour, preferably an hour.
2. You're going to need to clean up the spill inside your oven, or it'll burn more each time you use your oven until it carbonizes completely.  Wait until it cools and then scrub it with an appropriate solvent and brush or sponge.

Answer (score 1):

If it's the smell of smoke in the kitchen you need to get rid of, boil lemon (or other citrus) peel in water for about 15 minutes.  That should clear the air.  As noted by FuzzyChef, you'll also need to scrub out your oven so that you don't reintroduce the smell when you next use the oven.